# Why don't pinned email account notifications work after moving to a new phone?

Tags: email, windows-10-mobile, backup, pin-to-start

I had a number of email accounts pinned to my start screen on my old phone that was running Windows Phone 8.1.

When I was setting up my new phone, running Windows 10 Mobile, I was asked if I wanted to restore the backup from my old phone, which I did, and this recreated all of my old tiles in the same locations which was great.

What I have though is that whilst tapping on my email accounts took me to the correct inbox, I would not see any notifications of the number of new messages recieved. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The mail client in Windows 10 Mobile expects the tiles to have specific ids for the notifications to work - if you tap on the email account, bring up the menu via the <kbd>...</kbd> button at the bottom of the screen, you'll see that it doesn't think the folder is pinned.

If you re-pin it (and remove the old tile) you'll see that notifications will work once more.